# Using ReactJS with Sharepoint Rest API

Tags: sharepoint, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to use the React JavaScript library with the SharePoint Rest API to display and edit SharePoint Lists.  I've been able to get React to work inside of SharePoint, I'm using webpack-dev-server for development but it is difficult and time consuming.  Currently I mock up data for SharePoint Rest API calls and develop my code on webpack-dev-server.  When I get the code working. I compile the code for production and move the files to the SharePoint server.  I then test the new functionality in SharePoint.

React needs to run inside of SharePoint to access the Rest API. I don't think it is possible to set up the webpack-dev-server on the SharePoint server because SharePoint doesn't use actual folders to store files.  I tried to map a network drive on my windows computer to the SharePoint server but I was unable to get it to work.

I have just begun to work with JavaScript and React so I don't have much experience.

How can I make my development process easier?

Comment: did you end up with anything helpful?

Comment: I can now build and move the changes directly to the SharePoint with Webpack, but I still have issues debugging since the bundled code is minified.  I think it is possible to debug in SharePoint  but I haven't had time to work on it recently.  I hope to start working on this again next week.  But right now it is just a proof on concept so until I can show something useful to my manager it will just be a side project.

Comment: thanks for getting back on this. I am sure you will be able to get it working. There are bunch of references available to get it working. I will also be working on something similar and wanted to know if you are interested to share your code and collaborate to exchange ideas?